# Remove field in update form Entity (Symfony2)

Tags: entity-framework, symfony

I'm working with symfony2, and I have a form with a number of fields, one of them is called video.
Could be possible remove that field in the update form but not in the insert form?

(Form) YoutubepostType.php:

```
  $builder->add('tituloVideo')
          ->add('descripcionVideo')
          ->add('tagsVideo')
          ->add('video', 'file', array('required' => false));
```

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: The easiest way is to hide the field in your template.  If you really want to do it by examining the enitity itself then you need to add a listener to your form:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Ok, Cerad, thank you for your response.

Comment: In my experience, if the form field is not defined in your template, the form renderer will just add it again by default at the end of the form. So you can't simply "hide" it in the template. Cerad knows a million times more about Symfony than I do, so I'm not sure if that's what he is suggesting or not, but I don't think that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your controller is defining all the form fields directly, then you can just add an if statement after you define the main fields, to check if it's not an update before adding the `video` field, e.g.

```
$builder->add('tituloVideo')
    ->add('descripcionVideo')
    ->add('tagsVideo');
if($myMethod != 'update') {
    $builder->add('video', 'file', array('required' => false));
}
```

But assuming you have already defined a custom [form Collection of fields](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) then the field is defined in your form builder object already and you are just loading this collection in your Controller, then in that case you would just remove it:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyCollectionType(), $entity);
if($myMethod == 'update') {
    $form->remove('video');
}
```

If it's a field from an associated entity, you get the entity first and remove it from there:

```
$form->get('myEntityName')->remove('myFieldName')
```

Note: If you are manually creating your form template, and you just try to hide it in your template (e.g. set inside an if statement), it won't work:

```
{% if $myMethod == 'update' %}
    {{ form_row(form.video) }}
{% endif %}
```

The form renderer will just add it to the end of the form anyway (in my experience), so that won't work.